# Set a custom for actiobar using Android Studios

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I've tride to set another color for my actiobar quite a while now.
I've search on google and tried multiple solutions. but non of them have worked out for me.

The code i got now is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#cac09f</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This causes my app to crash and displays this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I then tried to set the theme to "Theme.Appcompat" but this wont change the color of the actionbar.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

I run this on a phone running android 4.4.4.
My project is for API 16 and higher (4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an activity from the support package (`AppCompatActivity`), it can only use compatibility themes (`Theme.AppCompat`).

The reason why setting a custom action bar background didn't work, is because you also need to use compatibility attributes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
  <item name="android:background">@color/my_red</item>
  <item name="background">@color/my_red</item>
</style>

<color name="my_red">#cac09f</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

guy I think that would be better you to use a toobar, because it is easier of work.

use this code in your xml:

```
           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tbMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"                   
                app:theme="@style/style_toobar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                />
```

in the style.xml use this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>      
</style>
<style name="style_toobar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

in the activity use:

`Toobar tbMain = (Toobar)findViewById(R.id.tbMain);
 setSupportActionBar(tbMain);`